# How can I get an uneven ground in webots

Tags: webots

I'm using webots to test my algorithms on a simulation robot model. I want to test my robot with an uneven ground to prove the robustness.I find a floor object called unevenTerrain in webots, which can randomly generated uneven terrain based on Perlin noise. It is okay, but I think I may need a more uneven ground than this object. How can I get an more uneven ground in Webots or is there any methods to create my own uneven terrain?

Comment: I would recommend you to make a copy of the `UnevenTerrain.proto` file in your local `project/protos` folder and modify it so that it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The uneven terrain PROTO uses internally the ElevationGrid node: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/elevationgrid

Using directly the ElevationGrid node, you can create a floor with any custom elevation (based on a regularly spaced grid).